# masstransit azure messages stop being picked up

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm facing following problem with MassTransit 3. I'm publishing messages from WebApi to Backend (ran as continuous webjob). When the backend job is started all works well and messages are picked up properly. After cca 20 minutes all messages published from WebApi stop being picked up by the backend. The message is published to the Azure Service Bus properly but is picked up only after restart of the webjob process.

MT debug log is completely silent and shows no issues. So this question is more for authors of MT if they could think of anything that could cause this issue.

[image]

**Update 1**

The web job is continuous and running in standard mode, therefore the 20minute  timeout mentioned in azure documentation shouldn't apply.

I've checked the logs and the job is running. Environment doesn't log anything about stopping the job and the process explorer shows the job. With quite high thread count (I have just 3 consumers). **All threads are in wait state.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. The MT process got stuck after spawning around 2k threads. The issue must have been in azure transport as trying the same configuration with Rabbit worked well.

After updating to newer MT version (.11 beta), the transport started to behave properly.

Answer (score 2):

You should be creating a cloud service and not a web job. Web jobs are not meant for continuous processes. A worker role is exactly what you need.

From the Azure documentation:

> Web apps in Free mode can time out after 20 minutes if there are no requests to the scm (deployment) site and the web app's portal is not open in Azure. Requests to the actual site will not reset this.

Comment: The app is not in free mode, it's set to always on and the web job is continuous. In this configuration it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Can you verify that the web job is still running? If all logging stops after 20 minutes, that seems suspect.

Comment: Verified and updated the question. All threads in that particular MT process are in wait. I'm not sure but I think that will not wake up.